# Generating RSA keys in Android in PKCS#1 format in Android

Tags: java, android, rsa, bouncycastle, logcat

I'm trying to generate an RSA public key in the form of PKCS#1 in Android.

There is almost an exact duplicate of this question here: [Generating RSA keys in PKCS#1 format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611383/generating-rsa-keys-in-pkcs1-format-in-java)

The author never responded with an answer though. I went through the answers, but I haven't been able to find something that works. I've come to the conclusion (unless someone else has a different answer) that it must be done using Bouncy Castle. The only problem I'm having with bouncy castle is actually using it in Android. I "seem" to have imported the jar correctly (I say "seem" because I've never done it before, but it was a fairly painless process and I get no errors in Eclipse) but, then I get an error in log cat.

```
03-25 22:25:58.780: E/AndroidRuntime(9171): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Comment: It is tricky to use BouncyCastle in Android as Android already uses a mangled BouncyCastle internally. SpongyCastle (https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frtyley%2Fspongycastle&ei=Yt9vT_C0G6O5iQfJ8e2TBg&usg=AFQjCNGhIK5nkAxRvqDovIe8E8RMtCaa6Q&cad=rja) was created for this reasons and works quite well for me (though I haven't tried your case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible answers.

If you want to go the way you're going, try this to resolve the `NoClassDefFoundError`.
[android eclipse updated and now app crashes when it trys to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835363/android-eclipse-updated-and-now-app-crashes-when-it-trys-to-run/9835447#9835447)

You can also use JSch instead. I have this working reliably on android myself.
[RSA Encryption forceclosing before generating public/private keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849207/rsa-encryption-forceclosing-before-generating-public-private-keys/9849333#9849333)

**Edit:** Here's an example of using JSch to generate RSA-type keypairs. I *think* it's PKCS#1, but I'm not familiar enough with the standard. The [relevant javadoc](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPairGenRSA.html) is what I'm going off of.

```
/**
 * Load or generate a RSA keypair to use as a client for the given JSch.
 */
public boolean registerKeyPair(JSch jSch) {             
    new File(getRootFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/.ssh").mkdirs();

    File privateKey = new File(getRootFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/.ssh/id_rsa");
    File publicKey = new File(getRootFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/.ssh/id_rsa.pub");
    if (!privateKey.exists() || !publicKey.exists()) {          
        try {
            KeyPair keyPair = KeyPair.genKeyPair(jSch, KeyPair.RSA);
            keyPair.writePrivateKey(privateKey.getAbsolutePath());
            keyPair.writePublicKey(publicKey.getAbsolutePath(), "Machine Shop");
            return true;
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            Log.e("genKeyPair(RSA)", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("genKeyPair(RSA)", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("genKeyPair(RSA)", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        return false;           
    }       

    try {
        jSch.addIdentity(privateKey.getAbsolutePath());
        return true;
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        Log.w("jSch.addIdentity", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        return false;           
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Assuming Eclipse. Include the [JSch jar file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar/0.1.46/jsch-0.1.46.jar/download) in your build path, preferably as a local jar (say in a lib folder). Make sure to check it on the "Order and Export" tab.

Now refresh your project.

Comment: I think I am going to pursue the BouncyCastle error but, http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ doesn't seem to mention anything about PKCS#1, or am I just overlooking it?

Comment: I believe it does, but that's just from looking at this: http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPairGenRSA.html. In either case, I've updated my answer with an example. Let me know if it's not PKCS#1, and I'll update it!

Comment: Sorry, to be totally honest, I don't know how to go about "importing" Jsch into my application. Little help?

Comment: The `getRootFolder()` methods are causing errors. Everything else is fine. Do I have to save it as a file?

Comment: The `getRootFolder()` method is from another member of my class--I just ripped that method out of my project :) And no, if you look at the javadoc link I posted up there you can navigate around and see in what other ways you can grab the keys.

Comment: Do I need to add anything to the manifest? I still can't get it to work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9298/discussion-between-sastraxi-and-eghdk)